# Как правильно загружать popup на страницу?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Сделал по быстрому всплывающие окно на jquery, примерно так:

```
popupHead  = $('<div class="ad__popup-head"></div>')
```

и таких тегов штук 10 примерно, потом вкладываю их в друг друга функцией append и в конце

```
$('body').append(popup);
```

Это то-что я быстро смог придумать. Сейчас думаю как улучить данную схему. Есть такие варианты.
1. Подгружать все нужные окна сразу на странице со всем html, но скрытыми. По клику показывать их соответственно.
2. Создавать в js эти окна, как сейчас это делаю
3. Создать какой-то файл этой разметкой, и подгружать её на сайт по клику.

В принципе 2 вариант нормальные но выглядит как неправильно что ли как мне кажется. 3 вариант мне кажется самый правильный, но тогда придется обращаться лишний раз к северу. 
Подскажите как лучше поступить в этом случае? может быть есть ещё какой-то вариант.

Comment: не проще в один поп-ап добавлять разную информацию?

Answer (score 1):

ИМХО

1 - Лучший вариант если разметка не очень сложная (если в попапе нужна формочка, сообщение какое или картинка)

2 - Этот вариант уместен только если у тебя на клиенте сложное приложение, иначе это доставит не мало хлопот, особенно тем кто потом будет поддерживать сайт

3 - Этот вариант наилучшим образом подойдет если в попапах нужно показывать много информации. К пример я делал как-то список кейсов и при клике по превьюшке в попапе появлялась подробная инфа с галереей, описанием компании клиента, задачи, предпринятых мер, результаты, похожие кейсы и форма. Для решения этой задачи безусловно не очень правильно было бы вываливать на страницу все эти подробные кейсы.